# Dynamic sort with large workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I can do some basic sortinng using vba however i cannot get things to work when i want to make it dynamic...
what i have done now is set a hard stop at 10k, however the workbooks i need to sort change rapidly in size.

what would be the best approach and why?

i have tried to set the "Range" to Range("a1:B" & lastrow), respectively for each select however this seems to hang and not execute the macro.

````
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Rapportage").Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range( _
        "A1:BZ1"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
        xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Rapportage").Sort
        .SetRange Range("A1:BZ9999")
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlLeftToRight
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Range("q3", Range("q5 : q9999")).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[1]+RC[2]"
    Rows("5:9999").Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Rapportage").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Rapportage").Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range( _
        "B5:B9999"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
        xlSortNormal
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Rapportage").Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range( _
        "C5:C9999"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
        xlSortNormal
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Rapportage").Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range( _
        "F5:F9999"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
        xlSortNormal
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Rapportage").Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range( _
        "E5:E9999"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
        xlSortNormal
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Rapportage").Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range( _
        "I5:I9999"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
        xlSortTextAsNumbers
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Rapportage").Sort
        .SetRange Range("A5:BZ9999")
        .Header = xlGuess
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With```
````

Comment: if `Worksheets("Rapportage")` is not the active sheet, the code would return an error. ` Range("A1:BZ9999")` refers to the active one. When you use `Key:=Range("A1:BZ1")`, what do you expect?

Comment: "Rapportage" will always be the active worksheet, key: =Range(.... 
a1 to bz1 contain certain indexes which i generate with some other code, looking at the names of the cells below, either 1 through 24 or blank
i sort the colums horizontally first according to the indexes, than i want to sort the rows with ascending from colums "b c f e i" in that order
.
.However the first row not always contains columns a trhough BZ sometimes a bit more

Answer (score 1):

I think your code should look somewhat like the procedure below. Note that the `Key` defines the column to be sorted on. It's specified by a single cell in it, usually in the first row but I chose the fifth because the first row is excluded from your range - not that VBA or Excel would take offence.

```
Sub TestSort()
    ' 041

    Dim Cell    As Range
    Dim SortRng As Range

    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Rapportage")
        Set Cell = .Cells(5, 2)

        With .Sort.SortFields
            .Clear
            .Add Key:=Cell, SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
                                        Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
            .Add Key:=Cell.Offset(, 1), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
                                        Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
            .Add Key:=Cell.Offset(, 4), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
                                        Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
            .Add Key:=Cell.Offset(, 3), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
                                        Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
            .Add Key:=Cell.Offset(, 7), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
                                        Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        End With

        Set SortRng = .Range(.Cells(5, "A"), _
                             .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(, 77))
        With .Sort
            .SetRange SortRng
            .Header = xlNo
            .MatchCase = False
            .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
            .SortMethod = xlPinYin
            .Apply
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Specifying the column to sort on is different from specifying the range to be sorted. That enters the code only after the keys have all been set and the actual sorting process is initiated.

Comment: okay after testing this makes sense...  
so if i want to do sort the columns by the first row i would set the cell to `.Cells(1,1)`
the sortfield to `Key:=Cell, SortOn=...` and the orientation to `xlLeftToRight` right?

Comment: the 77 in the offset is just to make sure you atleast have 77 columns within your sort right?

Comment: Not quite. It's a precise measure defining the last columns to be included in the sort. Enter `? Range("A1").Offset(,77).Address` in the Immediate window and the result will be $BZ$1. But `? Columns("BZ").Column` returns 78 because *BZ* is the 78th column. Of course, if you start your count not at zero but at 1 (column A), as you do with *Offset* the difference will be smaller. Still, whichever way, it's column *BZ*.